# How to implement Javascript-like dynamic typing in C++

Tags: c++, json, dynamic-typing

I have to write a very basic JSON serializer/deserializer in C++. The goal is to build something similar to this https://github.com/nlohmann/json. Unfortunately I can't use this awesome library because my compiler does not fully support the C++ 11 standard. Switching the compiler is not an option.

I would like to go with an approach close to the following examples. I am writing my idea in some sort of pseudo code, based on the [TypeScript Syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html).

I'm imaging a class representing a JSON object, with functions to access it's keys and get some dynamic values from them.

```js
type JSONValue = int | double | string | list | JSONObject | ...;

class JSONObject {
  private map: Map<string, JSONValue>;

  public set(key: string, value: JSONValue) { ... };
  public get(key: string): JSONValue { ... };
  public stringify(): string;
}
```

I think the general concept should be clear. Parsing a JSON string is not the problem. Creating a JSON string is trivial too. But creating a type like `JSONValue` in C++ is something I can't wrap my head around.

Probably the way to go are templates, but I need some guidance on how to implement such a "dynamic" type. I would like to get some example on how to approach this problem.

**Edit:** The code has to work in RAD Studio 10.2.3 with the Clang enhanced compiler. It's hard to tell what this compiler supports so I will test every suggestion and add the limitations to this question as they arise.

**Edit 2:** Running `bcc32x --version` yields the following results:

```
Embarcadero C++ 7.30 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2017 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Embarcadero Technologies Inc. bcc32x version 3.3.1 (36355.e71d049.f8c4cf9) (based on LLVM 3.3.1)
Target: i686-pc-win32-omf
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: You could try to use an older version of https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp or even go C-style with https://github.com/kgabis/parson.

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) would solve your problem, but it is C++17. Perhaps you can get your compiler to use it, or check out its implementation. But seriously, if your compiler is old enough to not support C++11, update your compiler.

Comment: Your environement seems to be quite up-to-date, are you sure you are using the correct compiler flags (e.g. --std=c++11 or --std==c++17)... ?

Comment: @bitmask There is a header only variant for pre c++17 compilers here: https://github.com/mpark/variant. From my experience it works decently well.

Comment: according to this site, youre clang enhanced compilers support c++11: https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/new-in-c-builder-10-2-3-a-new-win32-acompiler-front-end-bcc32x

What is your compiler version? Can you check that with ```bcc32x --version``` or something like that?

Comment: @yussuf I've added the output of `bcc32x --version` to my question

Comment: hm ok... sadly, clang version 3.3 is not officially supported by nlohmann::json :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you don't actually need fully dynamic typing, as `JSONValue` can't have any type, just some amount of different types. This is what you would use a `union` for:

```cpp
union JSONValue {
    long long integer;
    double floating;
    std::string string;
    ...
}
```

Unions of non-trivially destructible types are however quite unsafe, because you need to make sure that the destructor of `string` gets called, if `string` is the active member.

If you were using C++17, you could use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which is essentially a type-safe `union`. Before C++17 (in your case), [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) can be used instead.

Comment: There is an extra step to resolve: the recursion (Naive way would be `union JSonValue { /*..*/ std::map<string, JSonValue> dict; std::vector<JSonValue> arr; };`).

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at the source code to get some inspiration. For example [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/b9d76516a2f4e8102ecac5fd8ba0c8c97ce3c382/include/nlohmann/json.hpp#L966) you can see how Niels solved that problem: He defines a union `json_value` consisting of several pointers to the specific possible types. The concrete type of an `json_value` object is then stored in a separate value of type `value_t` defined [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/include/nlohmann/detail/value_t.hpp).

**Important:** If your compiler doesn't support C++11, the union is not allowed to contain non-trivial members. Since that, it can't contain a `std::string` only a pointer to `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you need something like a union. I recommend [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (or [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) if compiler doesn't support C++17).

Comment: There is an extra step to resolve: the recursion (Naive way would be `union JSonValue { /*..*/ std::map<string, JSonValue> dict; std::vector<JSonValue> arr; };`)